# Homebrew setup causing insecure directories and files warning in terminal

Tags: permissions, homebrew, zsh, multi-user

My console is showing this when opening:

```
zsh compinit: insecure directories and files, run compaudit for list.
Ignore insecure directories and files and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]?`
```

When I run `compaudit`, as the warning suggets, I get following insecure directories:

```
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/local/share/zsh
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew_services
```

So my asumption is it has something to do with my brew installation.
I am using an M1 Mac and have configured brew so I can use it on my private and my work user using these commands:

`sudo chgrp -R brew $(brew --prefix)/*` (Change the group of homebrew installation directory)

`sudo chmod -R g+w $(brew --prefix)/*` (Allow group members to write inside this directory)

So my question is how can I remove this warning?
Is it caused by my multi-user brew setup?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this issue by adding

```
ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX="true"
```

at the beginning of my `~/.zshrc` file.